# Selected value for DropDownList not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to set a selected value for my dropdownlist but I can't make it show on page.

This is how I set the selected value;

```
productHier = new SelectList(hierarchyList, "ProductHierarchyID", "ProductHierarchyCode", orderline.PrmProductVariant.PrmProduct.PrmProductHierarchy1 );
ViewBag.productHier = productHier;
```

and this is the part in my View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Hierarchy", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.productHier, "Hierarchy Seçiniz", new { @Class = "form-control control-text" })
```

I tried many suggestions from other question on this subject but none helped me. I wonder what I'm missing.

EDIT: When I debug, I can see the values designated as selected value in controller and view but somehow I can't see them on page.

Comment: Is `Hierarchy` a property in your model. If so, then set it to the value of the option you want selected (the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is ignored when binding to a model.

Comment: It's just the name of the Dropdown,  there isn't anything with name "Hierarchy" in my model.

Answer (score 0):

To bind `Hierarchy` value you need use `DropDownListFor` HtmlHelper as below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Hierarchy, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.productHier, "Hierarchy Seçiniz", new { @Class = "form-control control-text" })
```

*You must have `Hierarchy` property set in controller when you return View.*

Answer (score 0):

I think with the way you are doing it, you need to do it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("productHier", null, "Hierarchy Seçiniz", new { @Class = "form-control control-text" })
```

Beware, that this style of creating drop down lists does not work with validation.

You will have to use `DropDownListFor` in order to get proper validation.

Hope this helps!